# What would a medieval mech look like?

Tags: magic, warfare, weapons, medieval, materials

My kingdom has the tech and arncane knowledge to build mechs,A soul is harvested and trapped inside a crystal core to power the war machines,However im limited to medieval europe materials.

How would an efficient medieval mech look like?

They are semi-autonomous and single mage can control 100 of them behind the lines,The mechs dont need to be powerful,But they need to overwhelm the enemy and move fast inside enemy cities.

Thanks.

Comment: I recognize this has been put on hold, but it's worth pointing out that it's already been answered - by [Leonardo da Vinci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo%27s_fighting_vehicle).  And he didn't need magic.

Answer (score 3):

**A golem-like mech**

You are in medieval europe. People do not have the highly resistant alloy we possess. That alone, make it impossible for your mech to ressemble one of these giant metallic machine in science fiction. Instead, they will most likely build giants made of muds, rocks and stones and use your crystal core as the catalyst to make it fully functionnal.

Then, because they will found out about the power of *big freaking things* in the world of physics, they will discover that the golem self-destruct easily. For people of this time, who don't have much option when it comes to protect a body, they will most likely try to add layers to the golem. They will make him **an armor**, ressembling that of a knight in the first tries. With trials, they will throw out the iron layers (which doesn't protect anything) and replace it with leather.